# Gigabyte Z170X Gaming 7 Integrated Graphics Not Working

Tags: boot, bios, post, integrated-graphics

I was stuck in a BSoD boot loop earlier today.  I went to go reformat my SSD, but now I can't even get the PC to where I can access the bios.  My GTX 970 has stopped displaying anything as well, and both that and the integrated graphics display "No Signal" on my TV monitor.  I believe that I may have turned Secure Boot on in the bios earlier today, and that might be why it's not recognizing my graphics card, so I'm trying to get to the bios but I'm not able to boot.  How can I get my onboard graphics to work with an HDMI cable so I can access my bios?